# how to pass string variable to linq select new {} section

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-3.5

Ii just want to make search functionality with linq with multiple ColumnNames that stored to session variable. I'm using one method:

```
public void FillGrid(string CommandName,string ColumnName, string SearchText)
```

That has three string variable that stores session value.

Now I just want to pass ColumnName with this query:

```
var query1 = (from p in db.Posts
              join c in db.Categories on p.Category_id equals c.Id
              join u in db.Users on p.User_id equals u.Id
              where (p.ToUser_id == user_id || p.ToUser_id == null) && p.User_id != user_id
              orderby p.Sent_Datetime descending
              select new
              {
                  Id = p.Id,
                  Title = p.Title,
                  Publisher = u.First_name + " " + u.Last_name,
                  ToUser = p.ToUser_id,
                  PublishDate = p.Sent_Datetime,
                  IsFile = p.IsFileAttached,
                  CategoryName = c.Category_name,
                  status_name = (from s in db.Status where (s.Id == p.status_id) select s.status_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                  Group_name = (from g in db.Groups where (g.Id == p.group_id) select g.Group_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                  FileSize = p.TotalFileSize,
                  ColumnName = Sesssion["ColumnName"].ToString()
              }).Where(q => q.ColumnName.Contains(SearchText));
```

However, ColumnName does not give any text or it may be not part of this query i have to manually give column name because.

for multiple column i have, so i can not use this statement like:

```
.Where(q => q.Tile.Contains(SearchText));
```

this query works fine with single column. but there is multiple column i have so i have to set q.ColumnName from outer side.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. The initial version of your post had most of the query miles over to the right. Look at the preview before posting, and make sure it's how *you'd* want it to look if you were reading it with a view to answering.

Comment: (I've also edited the post in terms of English, but I didn't understand the final sentence, so you may want to edit that further to clarify it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do an extension method for that kind of things, building an expression for your predicate.

```
 public static class Helper
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterForColumn<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string colName, string searchText)
    {
        if (colName != null && searchText != null)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, colName);
            var searchExpression = Expression.Constant(searchText);
            var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
            var body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
            return queryable.Where(predicate);
        }
        else
        {
            return queryable;
        }
    }
}
```

usage in your case

```
var query1 = (from p in db.Posts
              join c in db.Categories on p.Category_id equals c.Id
              join u in db.Users on p.User_id equals u.Id
              where (p.ToUser_id == user_id || p.ToUser_id == null) && p.User_id != user_id
              orderby p.Sent_Datetime descending
              select new
              {
                  Id = p.Id,
                  Title = p.Title,
                  Publisher = u.First_name + " " + u.Last_name,
                  ToUser = p.ToUser_id,
                  PublishDate = p.Sent_Datetime,
                  IsFile = p.IsFileAttached,
                  CategoryName = c.Category_name,
                  status_name = (from s in db.Status where (s.Id == p.status_id) select s.status_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                  Group_name = (from g in db.Groups where (g.Id == p.group_id) select g.Group_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                  FileSize = p.TotalFileSize,
              }).FilterForColumn(Sesssion["ColumnName"].ToString(), SearchText);
```

Comment: I have to create one Class file with Helper in App_Code and inherits with content page class.

Comment: here error occured like : 'The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found'

Comment: @shal yes, corrected, It should be `FilterForColumn<T>` there was another typo on propertyexpression which should be propertyExpression.

Comment: one another error occured like : Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: well, yes, that's why I use `public static class Helper` which is not generic... You can use any class name by the way.

Comment: there is inheritance problem to i have already one class newManageClass as Base class for panel handling which is Public Class and c# doesn't supporting multiple inheritance.

Comment: But an Helper static class (whichever name you give it) doesn't need to inherit from anything...

Comment: how to handle this excenption like Value cannot be null. if i'm passing null column name and search text like this: this.FillGrid(string CommandName,null, null);

Comment: if null values found for column Name and search text then FilterColumn should be buy pass and query1 is like normal query without column filtering - most important

Comment: ya i handle on my shelf and it's works great for me. thank you